# amazon ec2 + msmq

Tags: amazon-ec2, msmq, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to set up a pub/sub msmq system and for this to work i need the instances to be on the same network. Is it possible to create a network in the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to create a private network/LAN between your machines.  There are a number of solutions, including setting up a VPN, or simply connecting to them directly using their private IP address, e.g. IPs that start with 10.

There's a related article on ServerFault with a similar question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/23222/vpn-lan-amazon-ec2-instances-how-to

Some have expressed concern regarding encrypting traffic between EC2 instances.  This is a good post related to encryption, which is a question related to your post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/10609/how-to-encrypt-traffic-between-two-amazon-ec2-instances

Finally, you'll want to set your firewall to allow inbound traffic from other EC2 instances:
https://serverfault.com/questions/33434/ec2-traffic-between-nodes